# Serialize data to binary using multicore

Tags: perl, serialization, multicore

I'm using the `store` function from the module `Storable` to get a binary representation of my hash. This hash is big enough for make the process last for 20min. Are there any similar function to `store` that works with multicore, so it gets the speed boosted?

I've searching for a while and I coulnd't find anything relevant, even using bson for the storage.

Comment: If you don't care about the format, you could literally split your hash into N parts then store the parts into separate files. /// Also, lighter formats such as JSON and YAML could very well be faster than Storable if they are sufficient for you.

Comment: Given the meaning of "serialization", exactly how would you propose to "serialize" something in parallel?  Also, even a gigabyte of data shouldn't take 20 minutes to serialize, something else is wrong.  If you want help you're going to have to provide a lot more detail.

Comment: @JimGarrison I have more than 1 gb of info. At this moment I can't say the exact amount, but I think that can be easy 10 gb. With serialize I mean getting a binary representation of my hash to store into a file.

Comment: @ikegami Thanks, I think that the splitting approach can help in this and it was my "back up" solution. I thought that maybe could be some developed approach to this, since I think that it's a common task. Changing the format, at this moment is not possible, but maybe in the future.

Comment: There's also [Booking.com](https://blog.booking.com/sereal-a-binary-data-serialization-format.html)'s [Sereal](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sereal). Not sure if it supports to use more than one core, but it's fast and the product is small.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that is single core, but much faster than Storable. So it's a good candidate

Comment: @ikegami I tried changing the format to JSON but file is 2mb bigger and a bit slower.

Comment: @simbabque have you any installable Sereal module download? since the one that is in github is giving me problems in the installation.

Comment: You can install it from cpan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I decided to split the data that I want to store in as many pieces as cores I have on the computer. So, I'm able to execute the `store` in threads making different output files, as ikegami suggested in the comments.